# Is it possible to provide sklearns KernelRidge a callable kernel that provides a Gram Matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to run a kernel ridge regression in python using the sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge function with a custom kernel (wendland kernel), that is not implemented in python, so I have to provide a callable (I want to avoide to use the 'precomputed' option in order to keep it in line with my other models). The problem is, that the callable has to return a float number, so it will be called once for each datapoint, which causes a real slow training.

Looking at a similar setup model, i.e. SVM.SVR, one has to provide a callable kernel function which returns the whole kernel matrix at once, which makes it much faster.

So my question is, if there is a possibility to make the KernelRidge function accept a callable function that provides the gram matrix in one step in order to speed up the process? Are there other alternatives?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.kernel_ridge import KernelRidge
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import check_pairwise_arrays, euclidean_distances

def Wendland_kernel(eps=None):
    #Kernel I want to use und am allowed to use with SVM.SVR
    def Wendland_gram_intern(X, Y=None, eps=eps):
        X, Y = check_pairwise_arrays(X,Y)        
        if eps is None:
            eps = 1.0 / X.shape[1]        
        K = euclidean_distances(X, Y, squared=False)
        K = 1 - eps*K        
        return np.maximum(K,0)**2    
    return Wendland_gram_intern

def Wendland_single(eps=None):
    #Kernel I have to use
    def Wendland_single_intern(x1, y1, eps=eps):        
        K = np.linalg.norm(x1-y1)
        K = 1 - eps*K        
        return np.maximum(K,0)**2    
    return Wendland_single_intern

X = np.random.random((10,2))
y = np.random.normal(size=(10,))

clf = KernelRidge(kernel=Wendland_single(eps=2.5))
clf.fit(X, y)
print(clf.predict([[0.5,0.5]]))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a great question! It has a clear problem statement, contains all the background, and the code example is self contained... I wish it would get more upvotes.

Comment: Here is an idea: what if you precompute the matrix and just look up the correct element inside the kernel function? (Not sure if this will have much benefit, though. The computation in the kernel does not look very expensive, so it is probably the function call overhead thet's slowing you down.)